# how to extract zip files into a folder with batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory, zip

i have zip files and am trying to unzip them with `powershell.exe -Command "& {Expand-Archive -Path zip_file_path -DestinationPath destination_folder_path}"`. for some zip folders it is creating a folder and extracting all the files into it and for some zip folders it is extracting all the files into the destination folder.

for example, `rough1.zip` is getting extracted to `rough1` but `rough2.zip` is getting extracted into the destination dir. ideally it should create `rough2` and put everything in it. what could be the reason? does different zip files have different structures? how to solve it?

Comment: You'll have to look inside of the zip files yourself since we don't have access to them. It's entirely possible that everything in rough1.zip is in a folder and all of the files in rough2.zip are in the root of the zip file themselves.

Comment: @SomethingDark, i looked at it and it seems like the structure differs between rough1.zip and rough2.zip. in light of this, how can i check rough2.zip and make sure that it gets extracted like rough1.zip. i guess i need to play with filenames.

Comment: Have the script make a folder before extracting the zip file and use that as the destination.

Comment: if i do that then `rough1.zip` gets extracted to `rough1/rough1` and `rough2.zip` gets extracted to `rough2`

Comment: Using .NET [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-7.0) you could "look" into the ZIP file before extraction, but it might be easier to just extract all files and move them one level up if necessary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There could be used a batch file with following code on having at least PowerShell 5.0 installed supporting the cmdlet [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*.zip) do (
    md "%%~nI" 2>nul
    if exist "%%~nI\" (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Command "Expand-Archive -LiteralPath '%%I' -DestinationPath '%%~nI' -Force"
        if exist "%%~nI\%%~nI\" (
            set "Other="
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%~nI\*" /A /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X "%%~nI"') do set "Other=1"
            if not defined Other (
                ren "%%~nI" "%%~nI_tmp"
                if not errorlevel 1 (
                    move "%%~nI_tmp\%%~nI" .\ >nul
                    rd "%%~nI_tmp"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

The batch file is designed to process all non-hidden files matched by the wildcard pattern `*.zip` in the current directory which of course can be any directory.

It creates first a subdirectory with name of the ZIP file without file extension `.zip` in the current directory.

If the directory could be created or existed already before, there is executed PowerShell to extract the current ZIP file into this subdirectory in the current directory. `& {` at beginning and `}` at end is not used as that is necessary only for a command block and not for a single cmdlet to execute by PowerShell.

There is next checked if in the subdirectory created by the batch file is now a **directory** (backslash at end is very important) with name of the ZIP file without file extension because of the ZIP file itself contained this directory which is the case for `rough1.zip` containing the directory `rough1` while this is not the case for `rough2.zip`.

There must be found out in that use case if the ZIP file respectively the subdirectory with name of the ZIP file in current directory contains only the **directory** with name of the ZIP file and no other **directory** or file or *link*. In other words there must be determined which of the following use cases occurs.

1. Destination directory contains only **directory** with ZIP file name

   - **ZipFileName**

     - **ZipFileName**

       - **Folder**
       - File.txt
2. Destination directory contains **directory** with ZIP file name and at least one more **directory**

   - **ZipFileName**

     - **AnotherFolder**

       - **Folder**
       - File 1.txt
     - **ZipFileName**

       - **Folder**
       - File 2.txt
3. Destination directory contains **directory** with ZIP file name and at least one more file or *link*

   - **ZipFileName**

     - **ZipFileName**

       - **Folder**
       - File.txt
     - One more file.txt
     - *Or a link*
4. Destination directory contains **directory** with ZIP file name and more **directories**/files/*links*

   - **ZipFileName**

     - **AnotherFolder**

       - **Folder**
       - File 1.txt
     - **ZipFileName**

       - **Folder**
       - File 2.txt
     - One more file.txt
     - *Or a link*

There is used a `for /F` loop to start one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line inside `'` appended as additional arguments. This second `cmd.exe` runs its internal command **DIR** which outputs all file system entries including hidden files and folders. The output list of **directory**/file/*link* names is redirected as input to **FINDSTR** which filters out the directory name being case-insensitive equal the ZIP file name without file extension and outputs to **STDOUT** of background command process all other **directory**/file/*link* names.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output names are captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and are processed by the command **FOR** line by line with always ignoring empty lines after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing the execution of **DIR** and **FINDSTR**.

The output names should not be split up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tabs as delimiters as done by default which is the reason for using the option `delims=` to define an empty list of delimiters. There is used additionally the option `eof=|` to define a vertical bar as end of line character instead of the default semicolon. A **directory**/file/*link* name can begin with a `;` in which case the line would be ignored by **FOR** by default which is not wanted here. But no file system entry can contain a vertical bar as described by Microsoft on the documentation page about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

The `for /F` loop just defines the environment variable `Other` if there are file system entries in the before created subdirectory with ZIP file name **not** having the ZIP file name. There is nothing output by **FINDSTR** for the first use case which means `for /F` runs never the command `set "Other=1"`.

In this case the directory created by the batch file itself is renamed by appending `_tmp`. It is very unlikely that this folder rename fails because that can happen only if there is in the current directory already a file system entry with ZIP file name with `_tmp` appended like `rough1_tmp` or another program has opened one of the files which were just extracted from the ZIP file. However, there is nothing done if the folder rename really fails for whatever reason. It is better keeping `rougth1\rough1\` in very unlikely use case then doing something wrong.

Next the directory with name of the ZIP file created during extraction of the ZIP file is moved up to the current directory which is just a very fast update of the entry for that directory in file system. There are no file data moved on storage media.

Last the now empty directory created by the batch file with ZIP file name with  appended `_tmp` is deleted from the current directory and remaining is for the first use case just the directory with name of the ZIP file as stored in the ZIP file itself.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `powershell /?`
- `rd /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer. i will go through it slowly. for now i just looped through all the directories and if there exists a parent and child directories with same name then i copied files to the parent dir and deleted the child dir. for now since there are no files in the parent dir except a child dir with the same name, it is working fine.